# attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.iterator java.util.list.iterator()' on a null object Volley

Tags: android, android-fragments, error-handling, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I am trying to fetch data from API and save it in local database but the problem is sometimes my code works perfectly and sometimes it does not work. It throws iterator exception. I am trying to debug it but not able to find any satisfactory result. Please help. I do not understand why my code run sometimes and sometimes not.

```
       private void callEventsApi() {

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = Constants.GET_EVENTS;
    final SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    final HashMap<String, String> loggedDetail = session.getUserDetail();

    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new JSONObject(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Log.e("event_response", response.toString());

                    Gson gson = new Gson();


                    try {
                        databaseHelper.deleteData();
                        ModelEvent modelEvent;
                        modelEvent = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ModelEvent.class);


                        if (modelEvent.getStatus() == 200) {

                            String status = response.getString("status");

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                            Log.e("tag", "instatus: " + jsonArray);

                            List<EventData> datumArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                            datumArrayList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), EventData[].class));

                            Log.e("TAG", "onResponse:size " + datumArrayList.size());



                            for (EventData eventData : datumArrayList) {

                                databaseHelper.addEventsDetails(eventData);
                                Log.e("tag", "onResponse56: " + datumArrayList.size());


                            }


                            for (int i = 0; i < datumArrayList.size(); i++) {

                                for (EventProduct eventProduct : datumArrayList.get(i).getProducts()) {


                                    Integer event_pro_id = datumArrayList.get(i).getEventId();
                                    Integer product_id = eventProduct.getId();
                                    String product_name = eventProduct.getProductName();

                                    EventProduct eventProduct1 = new EventProduct();
                                    eventProduct1.setEventId(event_pro_id);
                                    eventProduct1.setId(product_id);
                                    eventProduct1.setProductName(product_name);
                                    databaseHelper.addEventProducts(eventProduct1);


                                }


                            }


                            for (int i = 0; i < datumArrayList.size(); i++) {
                                for (Subevent subevent : datumArrayList.get(i).getSubevent()) {

                                    Log.e("tag", "onResponse13: " + subevent.getDate() + "&&" + subevent.getId() + "**" +
                                            datumArrayList.get(i).getEventId() + "))" + datumArrayList.get(i).getEventName());

                                    Integer event_sub_id = datumArrayList.get(i).getEventId();
                                    Integer sub_event_id = subevent.getId();
                                    String sub_event_name = subevent.getName();
                                    String sub_event_date = subevent.getDate();


                                    Subevent subevent1 = new Subevent();
                                    subevent1.setEventId(event_sub_id);
                                    subevent1.setId(sub_event_id);
                                    subevent1.setName(sub_event_name);
                                    subevent1.setDate(sub_event_date);

                                    databaseHelper.addSubEvents(subevent1);

                                }
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < datumArrayList.size(); i++) {
                                for (Subevent subevent : datumArrayList.get(i).getSubevent()) {
                                    for (EventBar eventBar : subevent.getBars()) {

                                        Log.e("tag", "onResponse14: " + eventBar.getName() + "&&" + eventBar.getId() + "**" +
                                                subevent.getId() + "))");

                                        Integer subEvent_bar_id = subevent.getId();
                                        Integer bar_id = eventBar.getId();
                                        String bar_name = eventBar.getName();


                                        EventBar eventBar1 = new EventBar();
                                        eventBar1.setSubEventId(subEvent_bar_id);
                                        eventBar1.setId(bar_id);
                                        eventBar1.setName(bar_name);

                                        databaseHelper.addSeBars(eventBar1);


                                    }

                                }
                            }


                            netStockApi();
                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), ContainerActivity.class);
                            startActivity(in);


                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.some_error_occured, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {


        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
              // handle error
            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + loggedDetail.get("api_token"));
            return headers;
        }
    };


    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            100000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
}
```

Comment: Probably datumArrayList or  getProducts() List is `null`

Comment: In the log, it will show you which line in code is `null`, then check your server side to know it is server bug or you need to handle `null`